# Можно ли в Android Studio разместить внутри проекта интерпретатор Python?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

**Можно ли в `Android Studio` как-то разместить внутри проекта интерпретатор `Python`?**

Иногда бывает необходимость использовать в Android-приложении какую-либо `Python`-библиотеку, возможностей которой на `Java` просто нет, либо они реализуются ну очень сложно.

Если такое можно провернуть, то есть еще 2 вопроса. **Откуда можно скачать подходящий для этой цели интерпретатор?** А также **как именно обращаться к нему из `Java-кода`?**

---

В качестве примера могу привести приложение [**Pydroid 3**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.iiec.pydroid3&hl=ru&gl=US). Здесь, как я понимаю, приложение обращается к интерпретатору, который лежит внутри приложения, а не где-то на сервере разработчика, так как приложение отлично и быстро работает и без использования интернета.

Comment: т.е. ради каких-то сомнительных возможностей пользователи должны будут качать раздутый апк с интерпретатором? Каких таких возможностей нет на яве?

Comment: ладно, здесь я приукрасил, что возможностей нет) во всяком случае, приложение делаю для себя, поэтому для некоторых целей мне проще использовать python, а разбираться с реализацией тех же действий на java лень. я уже сделал то что нужно на pydroid, но хотелось бы прикрутить к программе нормальную графическую оболочку в виде полноценного приложения

Comment: понятно, т.е. проблема XY :) вроде на kivy можно писать на питоне под андроид без всяких яв

Comment: спасибо, посмотрю